# How to Keep Selected listItem of Recyclerview Highlighted untill next Item of Recyclerview is been selected in xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
             myholder = holder as GeoFenceViewHolder;
            myholder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#000000"));
            if (selectedPosition == position)
            {
                myholder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#FF4081"));
            }
            else
            {
                myholder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ffffff"));
            }

```
        GeoFenceViewHolderItemClick(position);

        if (_lstItem[position].isApplied == true)
        {
            myholder.mradiobtngeofenceapplied.Checked = true;
        }
    }

    private void GeoFenceViewHolderItemClick(int position)
    {
       myholder.ItemView.Click += (sender, e) =>
      {
          selectedPosition = position;
          NotifyDataSetChanged();
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to Keep Selected listItem of Recyclerview Highlighted untill next Item of Recyclerview is been selected in xamarin Android

Just add this below line in `OnBindViewHolder` :

```
viewHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#000000"));
```

will work for you.

Highlight selected item just do like below :

```
//set it global
int selectedPosition = -1;   

public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
{
     ...

     if(selectedPosition == position)
     {
         viewHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#FF4081"));
     }
     else
     {
         viewHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#ffffff"));
     }

     viewHolder.ItemView.Click += (sender, e) =>
     {
         selectedPosition = position;
         NotifyDataSetChanged();
     };
 }
```

Effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk6y2.gif).

Comment: York selected item is getting highlighted..but by default next item in list is getting highlighted  by default

Comment: @Divya, could you please elaborate a bit more ? I cant reproduce your problem.

Comment: york when i select one item it gets highlighted and i delete that item (deletion is working fine),once i delete the next item is getting highlighted

Comment: @Divya, how did you delete an item, please post your code.